# Why isn't my recursive code returning (stopping)?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw some grass like elements in my canvas that is 989 pixle wide. I want it to run only one time and I want it to start from the left side and end at the right side. For some reason I am not able to end it with my given code:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("kasvupuu");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
      var r1,r2,r3,r4;
      
function muru(startX, startY, len, liblelai) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#356282";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#356282";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 15.5;
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
  ctx.lineWidth = liblelai;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.save();
  
  ctx.translate(startX, startY);
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -r1);
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.stroke();
  
  if(r3 > 9)
  {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rotate(r2 * (Math.PI/180));
    ctx.arc(startX, startY-3*r2, 3+r4, 0.1, Math.PI/1.5);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  }
  if(startX > 978)
  {
    ctx.restore();
    return;
  }

  r1=Math.floor((Math.random() * 18) + 1);
  r2=Math.floor((Math.random() * 180) + 1);
  r3=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  r4=Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  muru(+ 6-r4, 0, r1, liblelai-r4); //this is added to the marked string below.
  
  ctx.restore();
}
muru(11, 600, 18, 3) //the above muru function result will be added to the values in this string.
```

So this function "muru" should be adding most of the time to the startX value and when it reaches 978, it should stop... But for some reason it isn't and I can not step in to evaluate the function... And obviously I will get eventually stackoverflow due to this code...
Could someone explain it to me?

The page where this current script is written: [muru](http://www.classicrent.eu/kool/puukaksmuru.html)

With best regards,
P6tu

Comment: Did you mean to put: `muru(startX + 6-r6, 0, len+r6, branchWidth+r4-r3);`

Comment: Nope. If I add "startX" to the string, then it will constantly add 11 + 6 - r6 to the startX value, and that is not what I am looking for. And either way, the recursive code would not stop and will run amokk way past X position 978.

Comment: Then of course its looping forever, you are always doing 6 - r6.

Comment: r6 needs to be less than -984 in order to get out of the recursion in your case

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't change anything else besides not showing anything on the canvas. Just in case, I've uploaded the same code on a webpage:
http://www.classicrent.eu/kool/puukaksmuru.html

Comment: For example I tried:
`muru(+ 6-r6-978, 0, len+r6, branchWidth-r3);`
And I got a blank page...

Comment: The recursion only stops when `startX > 978`. How would `6-r6-978` be that big?

Comment: `r6` is a random number between 1 and 7, so `6-r6` is between -1 and 5.

Comment: @Barmar , yes, the `6-r6-978`is definitely not the way it should be, I understand that.
So the `muru(+ 6-r6, 0, len+r6, branchWidth-r3);` should be correct, because eventually startX would be bigger than 978 and this if clause should stop the loop. Right? At this very moment the code is done so, but it does not stop at 978. For just in case to make sure, I've set the limit now to 678, so it should stop almost at the middle of the canvas on the above page.

Comment: `startX` is `6-r6`, that will never eventually be bigger than 978.

Comment: I don't understand... It is. Otherwise it wouldn't reach the edge of the canvas that it at position 989. If you check the code on the above webpage, then it is clearly visible that it reaches the point and still keeps going... What am I missing here?
As I've understood, then this part:
`function muru(startX, startY, len, liblelai) 
{
###
muru(+ 6-r6, 0, len+r6, liblelai-r3);

  ctx.restore();
}
muru(11, 560, 36, 1)`
then the `muru(+ 6-r6, 0, len+r6, liblelai-r3);` is always added after the function to the line `muru(11, 560, 36, 1)`. Isn't it the way it works?

Comment: @P6tu Check out the source code of the page you linked - the function call does indeed add a number to the current value of `startX`: `muru(startX+3-r4, 0, r1, liblelai-r4);`.  These sort of recursive things are hard to debug - I highly recommend adding some temporary counter that calls a stop condition on X iterations, then `console.log` all the variables.  You can see that with your current code, `startX` (your escape condition) never goes higher than the number `5`.

Comment: So indeed, I have to use startX and grow that value... I have currently solved the infinte loop, but I had to have a silly amount of function calls to achieve somewhat what I was looking for...
I am sure that there is a more reasonable way to do this. Can anyone tell, how it would be better to skip those unneceasary `muru` function calls at the end of the script?